# How can I vertically align different height text using flexbox in Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a problem with vertically aligning text using `flex` in my web application using `Tailwind`. Here is part of my code:

```
<div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
  <div className="font-bebas bg-font-color ">
    <h1 className="text-font-color text-4xl flex flex-row gap-2 items-end">nothing but 
    <p className="text-secondary text-5xl self-end">the best</p></h1>
  </div>
  <h2 className="text-secondary font-nautigal text-5xl">Frank Sinatra</h2>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the text "nothing but" and "the best" in the same line. How can I achieve this?

[image: how it looks now]

Comment: They are already in the same line. What am i missing?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN You can notice that THE BEST is little bit higher, so it does look weird

Comment: It's just due to selection highlight, but the texts are actually on the same base line. If you want selection to looks the same height, you can set both of them a same value of `line-height` CSS property. This `line-height` will make both texts to occupy same amount of height within their parent element.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN it is good an idea, setted `line-heigt` as `leading-3` for both texts, but THE BEST text looks little bit cutted of.  See https://imgur.com/1i8c2nY

Comment: It's probably caused by the different font-sizes on texts. When you set `leading-3` on both texts with different font sizes, the class sets `line-height: .75rem` for texts. It's measured in rems, so calculated line-heights are different. Could you try setting a fixed line-height value on both like `leading-[9px]`?

Comment: With `leading-[9px]` it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/KiukeCh. it makes me wonder if the fault might be in the alignemt of the texts.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN chechkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seems to me like the proper way, but it works. I had to set bigger text `line-heigt` to `45px` and the smaller one to `15px`.

```
              <h2 className="text-font-color text-7xl  
               leading-[15px]">nothing but 
              </h2>

              <h1 className="text-secondary text-9xl leading-[45px] ">the best</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `<span>` instead of `<p>`
2. wrap both text in `<span>`

hope this will work as you expected.

```html
<div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
    <div className="font-bebas bg-font-color ">
        <h1 className="text-font-color text-4xl flex items-center flex-row gap-2">
            <span>nothing but</span>
            <span className="text-secondary text-5xl self-end">the best</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <h2 className="text-secondary font-nautigal text-5xl">Frank Sinatra</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Good an idea, but it works only for `text-4xl ` and `text-5xl `. Not for bigger `font-size`